# Dictionary construct in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Trying to build a function that constructs a dictionary from a given sequence, in Python.

Knowing that strings are immutable, and dictionaries are made of `key: value` pairs (keys are immutable while values are mutable), I opt to take a given sequence and scan for letter existence (lower & upper) in order to apply it to a key, and count its frequency in order to apply it to the appropriate value.

The main idea that i had so far is given below, support highly appreciated:

```py
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_letters
sentence = 'Check Sentence'
d = dict()

def dictionary_check(input):
    for i in alphabet:
        if i in input is True:
            #left empty for manipulation
            return
        else:
            return
dictionary_check(sentence)
print(d)
```

Sample input: `'Any string'`

Output: `{"A":1, "n":2, "y":1, "s":1, "t":1, "r":1, "i":1, "g":1}`

Comment: Sample input and expected output please?

Comment: What would you expect this to print for your sample input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
In [474]: from collections import Counter                                                                                                                                                                   

In [475]: sentence = 'Check Sentence'                                                                                                                                                                       

In [476]: Counter(sentence)                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[476]: 
Counter({'C': 1,
         'h': 1,
         'e': 4,
         'c': 2,
         'k': 1,
         ' ': 1,
         'S': 1,
         'n': 2,
         't': 1})
```

#### The above `Counter` object is already a dictionary.

#### After OP's comment, here's a custom function to do the same thing:

```
In [497]: def construct_dict(text): 
     ...:     d = {} 
     ...:     for i in text: 
     ...:         if i in d: 
     ...:             d[i] = d[i] + 1 
     ...:         else: 
     ...:             d[i] = 1 
     ...:     return d 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [498]: construct_dict(sentence)                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[498]: {'C': 1, 'h': 1, 'e': 4, 'c': 2, 'k': 1, ' ': 1, 'S': 1, 'n': 2, 't': 1}
```

#### For removing whitespaces, do the following:

```
In [507]: construct_dict(sentence.replace(' ',''))                                                                                                                                                           
Out[507]: {'C': 1, 'h': 1, 'e': 4, 'c': 2, 'k': 1, 'S': 1, 'n': 2, 't': 1}
```

Comment: Sir, this is exactly the target. But, i need help in constructing the dictionary  using non built-in functions, with no libraries import rather than "string" and no need for counting whitespaces.

Comment: @Mabadai What I fail to understand is, why would you need a custom function doing exactly the same thing as `Counter`? Isn't that's why the libraries are made?

Comment: You right thinking of the proper task for the right mission, indeed "counter" saves the date. Im new to python, thats why im trying to practice and understand what and how commands are working "behind the lines" of the code. In this example, i cant find the appropriate simple way to append keys and values regard the specific key, in order to built a new dynamic dictionary. I think my lack of knowledge begins in not understanding simple attributes in python. Regards.

Comment: @Mabadai Check my updated answer.

Comment: This helped a lot dear Maynak Porwal, thank you very much. Another question is if it possible to include bool flag in the 4th line of the code: "if i in d is not " ": " in order to avoid whitespaces?

Comment: @Mabadai No need to change the function for removing whitespaces. Just remove whitespaces from the `sentence` string. Check my updated answer.